# Unable to meaning of a statement in Multivariable calculus

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

The following image is from Page 346 of chapter 12 of Tom M Apostol Mathematical Analysis.
I have a question in the underlined part.

[image: r]

Question is -> What does author means by statement that error term is of smaller order than h?
What is use/ meaning of the word " order " here?

Comment: It is already defined in the paragraph below result 4. It basically means that error will definitely go to zero if h goes to zero. For example it might consist of powers of h greater than or equal to h.

Comment: We have here a deciding point in the formation of a mathematician. It is a pity that Apostol has not thought longer about the words, and formulas, he is using.

Comment: @Bhaswat No, necessarily a higher power. When we divide the term by $h$, the quotient must go to $0$ as $h\to 0$.

Comment: @Ted Shifein so in context of present question it means that $ h  E_{c} (h)$  / h must tend to zero as h -> 0 ? Kindly verify

Comment: Yes, that's right. Of course, once he moves on to vectors, things have to be stated slightly differently.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That an error term $\phi(h)$ is of smaller order than $h$ means that the *relative error* $\dfrac{\phi(h)}{h} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$. In other words, the error term goes much faster to $0$ as $h$.

Comment: Not necessarily "much" faster- just faster!

Comment: @Paul Frost what do you mean by " Relatives error" on line 2?

Comment: The absolute error depends on $h$ and has the value $\phi(h)$. The relative error is defined as the ratio $\dfrac{\phi(h)}{h}$.

Comment: @Paul Frost What does $\phi$ means in $\phi$(h) ?

Comment: @user It is the function assigning to $h$ the absolute error at $c+h$, i.e. the deviation of $f(c+h)$ from its linear aproximation $f(c) + f'(c)h$. We have
$$f(c+h) = f(c) + f'(c)h + hE_c(h) .$$

I have written $\phi(h)=  hE_c(h)$.